# How to replace a point ('.') in a string, with the word before the point?

Tags: java, string, replace, character

If we have

```
String x="Hello.World";
```

I'm looking to replace that `'.'` with `"Hello"`, as to have: `"HelloHelloWorld"`.

The problem is, if I have:

```
String Y="Hello.beautiful.world.how.are.you;"
```

the answer would have to be `"HelloHellobeautifulbeautifulworldworldhowhowareareyouyou"`

Keep in mind that I can't use arrays.

Comment: loop over the string. start building "last seen word" strings, and anytime you see a `.`, spit out that "last seen word", then start building again.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the dot into the string that precedes it?

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Why there are two `you` in your example (there is no `.` after it)?

Comment: According to your example, a semicolon should also be replaced?

Comment: yeah, but only to the word before the '.' ; once the first '.' has been replaced i need to take the next word (in the example it would be "world") but not the "hellohello" that i already got. In other words, i need a way to accumulate the string with the words duplicated and separate it from the main string so it can repeat the process

Comment: No, sorry, that was a mistake, the correct form was  "  .you");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the problem like a pointer problem. You need to keep a running `pointer` pointed at the last place you looked (`firstIndex` in my code), and a pointer at your current place (`nextIndex` in my code). Call `subString()` on whatever is between those places (add 1 to `firstIndex` after the first occurrence because we don't need to capture the "."), append it twice to a new string, and then change your pointers. There is probably a more elegant solution but, this gets the job done:

```
    String Y="Hello.beautiful.world.how.are.you";
    int firstIndex=0;
    int nextIndex=Y.indexOf(".",firstIndex);

    String newString = "";
    while(nextIndex != -1){
        newString += Y.substring(firstIndex==0 ? firstIndex : firstIndex+1, nextIndex);
        newString += Y.substring(firstIndex==0 ? firstIndex : firstIndex+1, nextIndex);
        firstIndex=nextIndex;
        nextIndex=Y.indexOf(".", nextIndex+1);
    }

    System.out.println(newString);
```

Output:

```
HelloHellobeautifulbeautifulworldworldhowhowareare
```

Comment: LGTM, but you should (probably) change it to append the string after the last dot. However, the question is not very specific about this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use regex replacements to achieve that. In a regex, you can use so called "capture groups". You match a word plus a dot with your regex and then you replace it with two times the matched word.

```
// Match any number of word characters plus a dot
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)\\.");

Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);

// $1 is the matched word, so $1$1 is just two times that word.
resultText = regexMatcher.replaceAll("$1$1");
```

Note that I didn't try it out since it would probably take me half an hour to set up the Java environment etc. But I am pretty confident that it works.

Comment: If he can't use arrays, I would assume regex is out of the question as well.

Comment: I am aware that there is this possibility, but for completeness, I wanted to mention this anyway. Either he can use them, then this should be a good answer, otherwise, he can update the question and ignore this.

Answer (score -2):

This is what i have:

```
public String meowDot(String meow){
    int length = meow.length();
    String beforeDot = "";
    String afterDot;
    char character;
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
        character = meow.charAt(i);
        if (i < largo - 1 && character == '.'){
            beforeDot += meow.substring(0, i) + meow.substring(0, i);
            afterDot = meow.substring(i, length);
            meow = afterDot;
        } else if(i == length - 1 && character != '.'){
            afterDot += meow + meow;
        }          
    }
    return beforeDot;
}
```

Comment: You should post your attempt in your original post.

Comment: This algorithm has a small problem. You change meow to the stuff after the dot, but then you don't reset the variable `i`, i.e. you continue at the wrong position.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix a user may answer their own question even if it doesn't work. Other answers will be upvoted if they're better

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I realize that, but I thought this was him posting his original attempt that was incorrect, not him saying that he solved it and posting an answer.

Comment: Usually people will post their attempt in the original post along with their question, then if they solve it, they will post their solution as an answer...at least from what I've seen.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix Very true :) It's a very poorly structured question and answer with little value for others. I've voted to close.